# A PHP script to publish book/documentation

Tags: php, php-easybook

I am looking for an opensource PHP script that will publish and organize table of contents. Something like Web2py book would be wonderful, http://web2py.com/book.

Thank you,

Comment: Related (but not PHP centered): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775503/minimalistic-tools-for-developer-documentation

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a very old question. But still I wanted to post my response as it might help someone who has this same question is their mind.

Try the below open source script (PHP) which can create books in HTML, PDF, MOBI and EPUB formats.

http://easybook-project.org/

Answer (score 1):

One option is the [PHP based Docbook renderer (PhD)](http://doc.php.net/phd/docs/) is a system that is used on PHP.net to produce the excellent manual pages.  It uses the DocBook format and produces appropriately linked, and organised multi-page documents.

> DocBook is a very popular set of tags
>   for describing books, articles, and
>   other prose documents, particularly
>   technical documentation. DocBook is
>   defined using the native DTD syntax of
>   SGML and XML. Like HTML, DocBook is an
>   example of a markup language defined
>   in SGML/XML.

[PhD quickstart](http://doc.php.net/php/dochowto/article.thequicky.exceptions.environment.php)

Comment: Thank you Alister. But, I'm not looking for PHP documentation. I'm looking for a php script to create an online book.

Comment: The same system can be used to write your own information. It's just a toolkit that the php docs use.

Answer (score 1):

You can download a PHP script from http://sourceforge.net/projects/myscrapbook/

It is a unique graphical internet content management tool that looks and acts just like a book. The PHP program can run using a text database or MySQL. You can set permissions to allow visitors to submit pages or only specific users.

Regards